# Querying List vs ToDictionary()

Tags: c#, performance, linq, collections, type-conversion

Imagine a situation where you have a sizable List which you need to search through. When would you convert it to a Dictionary<T.Identity, T> and when would you just query the list?

I am aware that querying a List is an O(n) operation, while querying a Dictionary (or Lookup/Hashset) is an O(1). However, I am entirely unsure of the efficiency of converting any O(n) collection into an O(1) collection. Isn't the efficiency of that conversion O(n) itself? Would that mean that converting a List into a Dictionary is entirely pointless unless you query it at least three times?

While we're at it, what's your thought process when you're deciding on a specific collection? What do you consider, and what do you find to be best practices?

E.g. (using my phone to write this, disregard syntax)

```
public class BigData
{
  public int Id;
  public SubBigData SubBigData;
}

//elsewhere...
public SubBigData GetDataById(int id) 
{
  List<BigData> data = GetDataFromSomewhere();

  return data.Where(d => d.Id == id).Select(d => d.SubBigData).FirstOrDefault();
  //vs
  return data.ToDictionary(d => d.Id, d.SubBigData)[id];
}
```

Comment: well, in your code sample, you're converting your data to a dictionary _every time_. which definitely is the _worst_ option.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Am I really? I'm not too certain on what exactly is happening under Linq's hood. If that's the case, it's terrible and I'd like to avoid that if I can

Comment: yes, you are - everytime you call `GetDataById`, you are calling `ToDictionary`. that has nothing to do with "under linq's hood". also: if the original source of `GetDataFromSomewhere` is IQueryable (a database for example), you should pass on your parameter - so you _only_ get the item you want.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Do you mean the ToDictionary at the second return perchance? This is for demonstration purposes, it's meant to be one or the other. Also, assume GetDataFromSomewhere returns List

Comment: The issue is you are calling `GetDataFromSomewhere` every search then you are calling `ToDictionary` every search. I think the correct answer is "Run your horses" e.g. measure the real world cost and performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I could filter the result before I get it, that would be ideal. So, if that `GetDataFromSomewhere` is query able, query your data there.**

#### Summary

I did a test to show actual results:

`On a collection of 1 000 000 records, get 1 000 records by ID`

The `Linq` expression in your example took `5.7` seconds.

A simplified `Linq` expression took `6.6` seconds.

The Dictionary conversion and retrieve took `26` seconds.

Interestingly, if you convert the entire collection to a Dictionary and use that as your new source, it will take `2.7` seconds to get 1000 records.

So, the Dictionary conversion is quicker here. *Though, I'm unsure if this is a sufficient test.*

#### Code

```
using System.Diagnostics;

#region Create and populate collection
List<TestObject> listCollection = new();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    listCollection.Add(new TestObject()
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = $"Name{i}"
    });
}
#endregion Create and populate collection

Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

Random random = new();

#region Get using Linq
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    int id = random.Next(0, 2000000);
    _ = listCollection.Where(c => c.Id == id).Select(c => c.Name).FirstOrDefault();
}

Console.WriteLine($"Took {stopwatch.Elapsed} to get 1000 items from list"); //Took 00:00:05.7212037
#endregion Get using Linq

#region Get using Linq (Shorter Expression, takes longer to execute)
stopwatch.Restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    int id = random.Next(0, 2000000);
    _ = listCollection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id)?.Name;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Took {stopwatch.Elapsed} to get 1000 items from list"); //Took 00:00:06.6697507
#endregion Get using Linq (Shorter Expression, takes longer to execute)

#region Get using Dictionary
stopwatch.Restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    try
    {
        int id = random.Next(0, 2000000);
        _ = listCollection.ToDictionary(c => c.Id, c => c.Name)[id];
    }
    catch {
        //Ignore errors when trying to get a value from the Dictionary that does not have a matching key
    }
}
Console.WriteLine($"Took {stopwatch.Elapsed} to get 1000 items from dictionary"); //Took 00:00:26.0257818
#endregion Get using Dictionary

#region Get using cached Dictionary
stopwatch.Restart();

var cachedDictionary = listCollection.ToDictionary(c => c.Id, c => c.Name);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    try
    {
        int id = random.Next(0, 2000000);
        _ = cachedDictionary[id];
    }
    catch
    {
        //Ignore errors when trying to get a value from the Dictionary that does not have a matching key
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"Took {stopwatch.Elapsed} to get 1000 items from cached dictionary"); //Took 00:00:02.7144331
#endregion Get using cached Dictionary

stopwatch.Stop();


public class TestObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that the shorter LINQ expression took longer to execute. It's fewer method calls; in theory, it should be more performant, not less.

Comment: I assume that when you're talking about the 26 second conversion to dictionary you mean the third region that converts on every single iteration of foreach? That makes a lot of sense, although I still was surprised by the operation taking such a significantly longer time, definitely something to keep in mind. 
The shorter query taking longer took me by surprise too, gotta research. Sidenote: although you should imagine GetDataFromSomewhere passes strictly List, if it were IQueryable, would it always be preferrable to keep it as such, only converting to a collection when strictly necessary?

Comment: @JohnnyCache, first let me say: I just realised your handle, and man, perfect. Back to the topic: I would make that method generic, let it return what I need. Probably a JSON conversion to what I require. But that's general practice in the things I create. So If I return multiple and want a list, make it a list, or a Dictionary thanks to an overload, or return a single object based on the query. Sometimes you'll need more than one method/overload, depending on the situation. At the end of the day, it will probably be a case by case. Performance testing etc.

Comment: @Marius I appreciate the wisdom! Makes sense to do things on a model-to-model, case-to-case basis for maximum performance, however what I'm looking for is a general rule of thumb: where would I consider using a specific solution or other, where I should just use whatever I want and not bother etc.

Comment: @JohnnyCache, that's tough. It's mostly going to be a case-by-case thing. For instance, if you use a `Dictionary<T, T>` to get via a unique identifier, it will be quick as in the example above. If you need to get based on another value that isn't unique in the collection, a `List<T>` with Linq will be your only option comparatively. Depending on the requirement, I personally use a the best match out of `Dictionary<T, T>`, `List<T>`, `Foreach` and `for`. Doing performance testing if you see bad performance will give you a clear picture of what to use. My go-to is `List<T>` with Linq.

Comment: @Marius List isn't necessarily the only option for non-unique identification. What about Lookup? Or Dictionary<(T1, T2), T> for complex uniqueness?
This poses another question of when is it efficient to form a Lookup vs querying a simple List. Looks like testing is the only way to do things right after all.
I think I'll just reserve careful picking and testing for actually sensitive methods for now